# Blank page when creating dynamic page with PHP MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a dynamic page with PHP and Mysql. It's just a simple blog that has a blog main page and links that go to the blog posts. When clicking on the posts I get a blank page. I think t may be my query thats the issue.

This is the code I'm using when a user clicks on a blog post link to read more:

I can see the correct ID goes into the URL just fine but nothing displays. Any ideas?

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'app');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `news`
    WHERE `id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."')
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2>' . ' ' . $row['description'] . '<br /><br />';
}


echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows;

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Just in case you need to see, here is the main page of the blog:

```
<?php
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'app');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `news`
SQL;

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo '<h2>' . $row['title'] . '</h2>' . ' ' . $row['description'] . '<br /><br />';
    echo '<a href="/blogger/showblog.php?id='.$row['id'].'">'.$row['title'].'</a><br /><br />';
}


echo 'Total results: ' . $result->num_rows;

// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()` with `new mysqli()`? Use a prepared statement/parameters.

Comment: don't really have to jump to prepared statements for such simple thing tho, a simple mysqli object with mysqli_real_escape_string should be fine there, for reference to mysqli on PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: Blank page is almost always a syntax error. You can get the php cli to syntax check a file for you. It helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error when using EOF because you cannot break and concatenate with quote or double quote.

```
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `news`
    WHERE `id` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id'])."')
SQL;
```

You should do:

```
$id=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
$sql = <<<SQL
    SELECT *
    FROM `news`
    WHERE `id` = $id)
SQL;
```

As for the blank page, I think you should get a error so make sure you have display_errors and error_reporting set accordingly so you see errors on the page.

I think with something like this should work:

```
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: side note: `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not work with `new mysqli()`

Comment: Also @Sean, thanks for the note on prepared statement/parameters. I will definitely look into that :)